# Existence of isothermal coordinates

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry

Can suggest me a good book to study about the proof of the existence of isothermal coordinates in a complex manifold with metric structure on it?I know about its definition but could not prove their existence.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A simple Google search "isothermal coordinates" reveals [this](http://soar.wichita.edu/bitstream/handle/10057/3968/t11032_Ragan.pdf?sequence=1) Master's thesis by Jennifer D. Ragan. It may be very useful for your purposes and contains a list of sources for further reading.

The Wikipedia's [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isothermal_coordinates) on this topic is also a valuable source of references.